# SASS sprite not working with @extend

Tags: sass, sprite

Hi I'm messing around with SASS and sprites, and it works fine. It generates a lot of clases from the filenames of my images, which I can use in my markup. 
But I would like to use the sprite without changing markup.

This is what I have

my images are located under images/raw
one of the images is called `spr-links.png`

in my css I have

```
@import "raw/*.png"; //Sprite
```

I should be able to to like this, but nothing comes out. SASS does not even fail on this

```
.footer{
    @extend .raw-spr-link;
}
```

Comment: Ok I found out that the way to write it is like this
@include raw-sprite(spr-links);

However the output is
background: url('/images/raw-s8e422df81e.png') no-repeat;
can I change this so it referes to
background: url('../images/raw-s8e422df81e.png') no-repeat; ??

Answer (score 1):

Just uncomment `"relative_assets = true"`

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

    # Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
    http_path = "/"
    css_dir = "css"
    sass_dir = "sass"
    images_dir = "images"
    javascripts_dir = "js"

    relative_assets = true

    output_style = :expanded # by Compass.app 
    sass_options = {:debug_info=>false} # by Compass.app 

    line_comments = true # by Compass.app
```