# Why is my Compass spriting not linking to the right image?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to use CSS sprites in my website, and I have before with Compass, but the image link is ever so slightly off for my pictures today.

I have a project root with an index.html file in it, then a styles/ folder, a style.css file and a sass folder in that with style.scss.

My config.rb file, which is within the styles folder from the root, looks like:

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = ""
sass_dir = "sass"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
images_dir = "../images"
output_style = :compressed
```

And I'm trying to show the images with:

```
a {
    @include twitter-sprite(twitter-icon);
    display: block;
    height: 27px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 31px;

    &:hover {
        @include twitter-sprite(twitter-icon-hover);
    }
}
```

I also have `@import "compass";` at the top.

I have this in my HTML: `<a href="http://twitter.com/syllableapp"></a>`

And I basically just want to set the background.

But whenever I try to view the image on the webpage, it won't show up, but the box is still clickable. When I inspect it, it says the address is`/../images/whatever`.

Comment: Possibly related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590031/sass-sprite-not-working-with-extend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `http_images_path` to [the full http path to images on the web server](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/).

In your case Compass is inferring `http_images_path` = `http_path` + `images_dir` = `/../images/`.

Setting `relative_assets = true` may also solve it.